# How to setup DNS manager for multiple IPs

Tags: apache-2.2, networking, domain-name-system, ip, lamp

I'm currently running a LAMP server with 2 IPs provided by 2 different ISPs. I use GoDaddy as my DNS manager but now that I have 2 IP addresses, I need the domain name to resolve the user to the fastest IP address for that specific user.

How do I go about doing this? 
I think I need an intelligent DNS that can figure out if the user is on the same ISP as the IP addresses.

Comment: This sounds like a premature optimization for me. Simply use two DNS A-records instead.

Comment: Actually, this is very common in China (Where I am located). You have two main ISPs (China Unicom and China Telecom), so many hosting providers allow your server to have 2 IPs. Users with Unicom will have significantly faster speeds on Unicom IP-addressed servers and Telecom users will be faster going to Telecom IP-addressed servers.

Comment: But if the user has the same ISP as your server, they should be routed to your server using that network by the ISP anyway.

Comment: The hosting provider gave us a server with one ethernet card but it has the two IPs bound to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started using this service called dnspod.cn. They provide intelligent routing for the different ISP IPs in China via their DNS manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, try Ultradns.

Else personally, dont bother. Just create two A records to both IPS and then if you can, set a decent TTL for for the zone.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you return both IPs and your user's system would use [destination address selection](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3484#section-6) to pick the right one. However, I believe that for IPv4 only some Windows versions do this.

When running your own name server is an option you can use bind with [views](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/oreilly/networking/news/views_0501.html) to provide a different zone for different net ranges.